# What is the general solution to $xdy/dx-y=x$ on $(-\infty,0)$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Just began learning differential equation. First thing I saw was 1st order linear differential equation. This is a practice problem.

$$x\frac{dy}{dx}-y=x$$

I have to find a general solution, one with arbitrary constant C on the interval $(-\infty,0)$. My textbook found the solution for the other interval, now I wondering about this.

My approach is to first turn it into $\frac{dy}{dx}-\frac{1}{x}y=1$, then use the formula $y=\frac{1}{\mu}\int{\mu q(x))}dx$
$q(x)=\frac{dy}{dx}+p(x)y=q(x)$
And $\mu (x)=e^{P(x)}$. P(x) is any integral of p(x) on that open interval.

On this negative open interval $\mu=|\frac{1}{x}|$.

So $y$ the solution is always positive. Thus $y=|x|ln|x|+C|x|$.

Is this right?

Comment: Yes, you have done it correctly.

Comment: @User8128, for $\mu$ why doesn't P(x) anti derivative of p(x) come with a constant?

Comment: It can: good observation! Try putting an arbitrary constant in there. If you do everything correctly it won't change anything. If you still don't see exactly why, I'll post an answer later explaining the whole thing. Let me know if you'd like me to do that.

Answer (score 1):

$$xy'(x)-y(x)=x\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\frac{xy'(x)-y(x)}{x}=\frac{x}{x}\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\frac{xy'(x)-y(x)}{x}=1\Longleftrightarrow$$

---

Let $r(x)=\exp\left[\int-\frac{1}{x}\space\text{d}x\right]=\frac{1}{x}$.

Multiply both sides by $r(x)$:

---

$$\frac{y'(x)}{x}-\frac{y(x)}{x^2}=\frac{1}{x}\Longleftrightarrow$$

---

Substitute $-\frac{1}{x^2}=\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$:

---

$$\frac{y'(x)}{x}+y(x)\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)=\frac{1}{x}\Longleftrightarrow$$

---

Apply the reverse product rule to the left-hand side:

---

$$\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}\left(\frac{y(x)}{x}\right)=\frac{1}{x}\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\int\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}\left(\frac{y(x)}{x}\right)\space\text{d}x=\int\frac{1}{x}\space\text{d}x\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\frac{y(x)}{x}=\ln|x|+\text{C}\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$y(x)=x\left(\ln|x|+\text{C}\right)$$

Comment: Why is the "x" outside the parentheses not an absolute value?

Comment: What made you want to multiply both side by the integration factor, did you foresee that it will simplify the result?

Comment: Why is the integration factor $\mu=e^{P(x)}$? How was it derived?